# CSS Grid iOS gap issue

Tags: html, css, ios, css-grid

Hopefully straight forward issue. Created an image gallery that is responsive using CSS grid and HTML only. All works perfectly on desktop and android phones using chrome and firefox. On iOS however there are a number of issues in mobile view only.

The challenge is with aspect ratios of the images which are all sized to 400px x 533px, so portrait images. Here is the code:

```
            <h2>Gallery</h2>
            <p>Check out some of the work we've done in our gallery below. Fortunately we 
                specialise in shining and shoes and not taking photos, eh! Check out our 
                instagram for more before and after photos!</p>
            <div class="image-gallery">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/Grenson 1.jpg" alt="worn mens Grenson boots">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/Grenson 2.jpg" alt="Cleaned and shined mens Grenson boots">
                <img id="large-img-1" src="./images/FS Gallery/Selection 1.jpg" alt="Collection of shiny leather shoes">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/Laces 1.jpg" alt="Pair of cracked, brown mens shoes with no laces">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/Laces 2.jpg" alt="Pair of shiny, mens brown shoes with blue laces">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/mirro.jpg" alt="Mirror effect on toe cap of black pair of Wildsmith boots">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/David 1.jpg" alt="Pair of cracked, black Ducker monk shoes">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/David 2.jpg" alt="Pair of shiny, black Ducker monk shoes">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/DM 1.jpg" alt="Pair of worn out, brown Dr. Marten boots">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/DM 2.jpg" alt="Pair of restored brown Dr. Marten boots">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/Loake 1.jpg" alt="Pair of water-stained, black Loake's">
                <img src="./images/FS Gallery/Loake 2.jpg" alt="Pair of shiny, black Loake's">
            </div>
        </section>
```

CSS Code

```
.image-gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 7.8rem;
    
}
.image-gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    border: 0.3rem white solid;
}
```

So there are multiple issues with using different solutions:

1. removing object fit - the images do not retain their aspect ratio and stretch out
2. object-fit: contain (as in the code above)- The image somehow stretches out vertically in iOS which gives the visual effect of large gaps between each photo. This is not an issue in android
3. Object-fit: cover - This zooms in somewhat, which I totally get why and is not a solution but I have included in case anyone suggests this.

Any solutions that retain aspect ratio and not create a large gap within the border of the image?

[Android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Mei.jpg)

[iOS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRH4J.jpg)

Site can be found: https://fulhamshoeshine.netlify.app/

Thanks!

Comment: Just use width:100% and remove the height and object-fit to get a proportional image?

Comment: Unfortunately removing the lines means that the desktop view with images in different grid areas would not span the entire height of their assigned rows. It also does not fix the issue.

Comment: maybe supply a minimal reproduction of your code, I doubt someone will help on this otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the HTML but I mean it is pretty basic. The CSS code is already there. It is minimal coding so I had hoped the issue would be somewhat easy to fix, but alas.

Answer (score 0):

As I was unable to source any answers or suggestions from the community nor any other sources, my work-around. should anyone encounter this situation in the future, was as follows:

Create query at breakpoint for mobile view and change the gallery display from grid to flex. Flex direction column.

Whilst it does not address the issue with grid on iPhone view it does offer a consistent UX across all devices.